# google drive v3 creating file when asked to create a folder within a folder

Tags: google-drive-api, directory, subdirectory

I am running the following using Google Drive API v3

```
const { result: { id: _spotDataFolderId } } = await drive.files.create({
            resource: { name: 'SPOT_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' }
        });
 const { result: { id: _patientsDataFolderId } } = await drive.files.create({
            resource: { name: 'PATIENTS_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' },
            parents: [ _spotDataFolderId ]
        });
```

I can see the first folder, `SPOT_DATA`, getting created. However, within `SPOT_DATA`, a file called `Untitled` is getting created. How do I create a subfolder called `PATIENTS_DATA` within `SPOT_DATA`

Note:

I am using async/await pattern. The `SPOT_DATA` folder is getting created. Further, if I remove `parents: [ _spotDataFolderId ]` from the second call, a folder `PATIENTS_DATA` is getting created in the home dir of my Google drive.

Comment: I see one possible problem, you should not be creating the second folder until the first await has completed. Maybe you need to nest the second call inside the response from the first?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it closely enough.

Comment: @Amarsh If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. Can I ask you about your question? 1. You are using Node.js and googleapis for requesting to Drive API? 2. If you are using googleapis, what version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Politest person I have met this week :) I am using the browser version of Google v3 APIs, all in JavaScript. It is a React App

Comment: @Amarsh Thank you for replying. I misunderstood about the language. I apologize. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution for your issue, if you confirmed that ``_spotDataFolderId`` has the correct folder ID, as a modification, for example, how about including ``parents`` in ``resource`` like ``resource: {name: 'PATIENTS_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', parents: [_spotDataFolderId]}``?

Comment: @Amarsh If ``_spotDataFolderId`` cannot be retrieved using ``{ result: { id: _spotDataFolderId } }``, can you test by modifying to ``{ data: { id: _spotDataFolderId } }``?

Comment: hey @Tanaike - `resource: {name: 'PATIENTS_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', parents: [_spotDataFolderId]}` worked :) can you please answer this as an *answer* so that I can mark it as correct. ps: your politeness is worths a three bows 

Comment: @Amarsh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? In this modification, the property of `parents` is included in `resource`.

#### From:

```
{
  resource: { name: 'PATIENTS_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' },
  parents: [ _spotDataFolderId ]
}
```

#### To:

```
{
  resource: { name: 'PATIENTS_DATA', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', parents: [ _spotDataFolderId ] },
}
```

#### Reference:

- [create method of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)